# What is the area of this figure? I can't quite figure it out

Tags: geometry

[image]

I can figure it out as a decimal, but it's asking me for it in radical form.

Comment: How are you getting it as a decimal?

Comment: I would like to know also!  It looks to me like there is not enough information.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's enough information to tell. How do you know what the base length is?

Comment: @samarbarrett You can know from the picture. It's $5$ . You can see a parallelogram there.

Comment: I know the base (5, because that's the hypotenuse of that right triangle), and the height is 3, then from there the area of the main paralellogram is 15, and the smaller triangle's area is 12, so that makes the whole thing.... huh. Well, looks like all I needed to do was explain it to someone else. Am I right, at least, that it's 27?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It looks like it's not drawn to scale

Comment: There is enough information.  The series on the sides of the quadrilateral inducate that opposing sides are congruent (thus forming a parallelogram).

Comment: @EricWofsey The area would be $21$. It is area of parallelogram + area of triangle. $=5*3 + 0.5*4*3=21$

Comment: @MattD Hey, the area of the small triangle is $6$

Comment: Yep, forgot to divide it by 2 - thanks, Win